# Loop through list in model passed as a list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, loops, view

This is the model I pass to my view as list:

```
    public class DogContentPage : ContentPage
    {

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public bool IsFemale { get; set; }

    public string Image { get; set; }
    public List<string> Merits { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model List<EmmysBlog_Core.Models.Dog.DogContentPage>
```

As you can see the model contains a list of strings (Merits). I have troubles looping through the list of Merits. Im suspecting that the reasin for this is that i pass the model as a list..Is it possible for me to loop through merits?

This attempt:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
       {
          <li>@item.Merits</li>
       }
```

Only gives me a list of:
System.Collection.Generic...

Do I have to change the way I pass the model to the view or is there another way of constructing the loop in order to access the values in Merits?

View:

```
@foreach (var dogs in Model.Where(o => o.IsFemale))
                {
                    <div class="media">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="@dogs.Image" style="width: 100%">
                            </a>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
                            <a href="#"><h3 class="media-heading">@dogs.Name</h3></a>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Stamtavla", "Dog", "Home", new { pageId = dogs.Id }, null)

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <ul>
                                @foreach (var item in Model)
                                {
                                     foreach (var merit in item.Merits)
                                     {
                                         <li>@merit</li>
                                     }
                                }

                            </ul>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add another `foreach` for the `Merits` list

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
   foreach (var merit in item.Merits)
   {
      <li>@merit</li>
   }
```

**Update**

Then just strip off the outer loop:

```
   foreach (var merit in dogs.Merits)
   {
       <li>@merit</li>
   }
```

Comment: Aha thank you! I gotta remeber this one! Will mark as answer asap

Comment: Your answer did exactly what I asked. However, I was not clear enough in my question..The thing is that the code you helped with is contained in another loop..This brings me some trouble cos it loops through all my dogs merits. If you have the time, please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do something like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
   {
     <ul> 
     @foreach(var merit in item.Merits)
     {
         <li>@merit</li>
     }
     </ul>
   }
```